# Now that ActiveRecord::Base.silence {} is gone, how do I bring back that functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, deprecated, silent

I do a lot of spatial queries that dump massive amounts of text in the form of logs every time I run queries. These slow down my programs enormously.

I'm being forced to update my rails to '4.1.2' from '4.0.0' and `ActiveRecord::Base.silence` has been completely deprecated as in, it doesn't work. Here's what used to work

```
ActiveRecord::Base.silence do
  noisy_query
end
```

When I try this now, I get this error....

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
from /Users/davidddouglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:82:in `capture'
```

In 4.0.0 it sent a deprecation warning, and now the script just doesn't work. Oddly enough, the function is still declared, it just doesn't work anymore and expects some kind of parameter. I've tried passing in `nil` and got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `reopen' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm looking for a way to monkeypatch the old functionality back into my program to get my scripts to work again. Not too worried about best practices as this is an application I'm using internally with little to no front end and 0 users other than myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`silence` moved to a [core extension on logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#silence).

From their example,

```
logger = Logger.new("log/development.log")
logger.silence(Logger::INFO) do
  logger.debug("In space, no one can hear you scream.")
  logger.info("Scream all you want, small mailman!")
end
```

Comment: Not that I'd really care at this point, because I never analyze my logs, but would `Logger.new("log/development.log")` erase my previous logfile?

Comment: Nope, it only instantiates a new `Logger` object that appends to the file you name. In case there's confusion, that `new` is only so their example runs. You probably want to be using `Rails.logger`, which is configured at boot.

Comment: Didn't work for me, got error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `reopen' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: [4.1.2 has LoggerSilence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.2/classes/LoggerSilence.html#method-i-silence) and this does the correct thing for me: `Rails.logger.silence(Logger::FATAL) { Rails.logger.info 'test' }`. Is that what you're running?

Comment: the logs that are getting executed are those that are automatically logged, i.e. the logs are happening without directly utilizing the logger object.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger` is the same object as `Rails.logger` (unless you've reconfigured them), so this should cover both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78738/discussion-between-boulder-ruby-and-kristjan).

Comment: I ended up switching my rails application back to its previous version, so this thread is bunk given the fact that I can't change/test it now

Comment: *shrug* Here's [an example](https://gist.github.com/kristjan/d8a6680b07a661833045) in one of my Rails applications.

Comment: OK, I got it to work. really frustrating it's gotten this complicated. I guess I'll use a keyboard shortcut in my text editor to make writing this out less painful. Looks like I can't use a lambda or a function to abbreviate the coding unless I use eval()....

Comment: That does sound overly complicated. Have any public code?